# ObjectDataSource does not call SelectCount Method

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, objectdatasource

can you please help me to find the problem:

I want to implement simple DataGrid and ObjectDataSource bundle with paging

**my .aspx file**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server"
 DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 
 AllowPaging="true"

 PageSize="2" >
</asp:DataGrid>
<asp:ObjectDataSource
 runat="server"
 ID="ObjectDataSource1"

 TypeName="WebApplication1.AssetComments"

 SelectMethod="SelectMethod2"
 StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex"
 MaximumRowsParameterName="maximumRows"
 SortParameterName="sortParameter"

 SelectCountMethod="GetCount" EnablePaging="True"
/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**My AssetComments class**

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
 public class AssetComments
 {

  public List<RSSFeed> SelectMethod2(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string sortParameter)
  {
   return SelectMethod2().Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows).ToList();
  }


  public List<RSSFeed> SelectMethod2()
  {
   List<RSSFeed> ret = new List<RSSFeed>(2) { new RSSFeed("11", "1111111"), new RSSFeed("22", "2222222") };

   return ret;
  }


  public int GetCount()
  {
   return 55;
  }
 }


 public class RSSFeed
 {
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }

  public RSSFeed(string title, string description)
  {
   Title = title;
   Description = description;
  }
 }
}
```

for some reason asp.net cals SelectMethod2 with (0,0,"") parameters and does not call GetCount.

please help me find the problem

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a GridView instead?

Comment: i'm facing the same problem even if i'm using gridview. any ideas ?

Comment: @Florjon, it might be better to start a new, more specific, question with a relevant sample of the code that's giving you a problem :)

Comment: @IrishChieftain you might have a look please, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260570/selectcountmethod-in-objectdatasource-isnt-called